# i have a html page from which i need to fetch the contents from that file using a tcl code

Tags: html, scripting, tcl

My HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title style="font-size:30px">sourceFile</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="font-size:20px">metal1</h1>
<p>count:90 </p>
<p>colour:red</p>
<p>change:yes </p>
</body>
</html>

<h2 style="font-size:20px">metal2</h2>
<p>count:340 </p>
<p>colour:brown</p>
<p>change:no </p>
</body>
</html>
```

My Tcl code to fetch the data from the HTML page

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set f [open comment.html]
set data [read $f]
close $f

puts $end
```

I'm going wrong somewhere. I'm expecting the contents of `<h1>` and `<h2>`.

Comment: Well, your HTML code has `</body>` and `</html>` twice. That's definitely a problem.

Comment: What's the problem? You read the file and ... what? Are you expecting something different from the contents of the file? `puts $end` there's no `end` variable in your code.

Comment: You're looking for just the strings `metal1` and `metal2`?

Comment: @DonalFellows yes i am looking for metal1 and metal2 details(count,colour,change) to be printed when i run the tcl code

Comment: @glennjackman sorry for the typo, its not $end but $data since i wanted to print what i read from the html file

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML is complicated and messy. We tend to recommend using the tDOM package for the task:

```
package require tdom 

set doc [dom parse -html $data]
foreach node [$doc selectNodes //h1] {
    puts [$node asText]
}
```

That will print `metal1` and could find the payload parts afterwards with suitable XPath wizardry (or by using the `nextSibling` method):

```
foreach node [$doc selectNodes //h1] {
    while true {
        puts [$node asText]
        set node [$node nextSibling]
        if {$node eq "" || ![string match *:* [$node asText]]} break
    }
}
```

It doesn't find `metal2` because of the error in the document (spurious `</body></html>`) as that tells the parser that the document stops there.